# is there a way to open a workbook when its name is a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

The title might be confusing.

What I meant was, say I have the path and file saved under a variable.

```
sPath = "C:\Users\"

sFile = "*1234*.*"

sWorkbook = sPath & sFile
```

The idea is that the sFile should be as vague as possible to account for any file names which may come through this folder. However, now that I have the file name saved under the sWorkbook variable, I have no idea how to open it by referencing sWorkbook; e.g. workbooks.open("sWorkbook").

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba/10382861#10382861

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Dir` function to get the filename you want

```
sPath = "C:\Users\"
sWildcard = "*1234*.*"
sFile = Dir(sPath & sWildcard)
If sFile <> "" Then
  sWorkbook = sPath & sFile
  Workbooks.Open sWorkbook
Else
  Msgbox "File Not Found"
  ' Exit Sub '// optionally exit the subroutine so that it does not try to continue //
End If
```

Comment: I would leave that up to the OP. Perhaps it is a CSV file.